# Objective-C - Set property value from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got a ViewController called `ThirdViewController`. `ThirdViewController` has a `UITabBarItem` (it's a tabbed application) declared as

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabItem;
```

I would to set `tabItem.badgeValue` from another class, in my case `AppDelegate`.

I tried to do

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
```

in `AppDelegate.h` and then

```
ThirdViewController *obj = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
    obj.tabItem.badgeValue = @"!";
```

in `AppDelegate.m`, but `obj.tabItem` is always `nil`..

How can I do?

Comment: Surely you want to set the property of an existing, active, view controller? Creating an instance, setting a property and then letting the instance be deallocated will do nothing, will it.

Comment: *it doesn't work..* is not a proper description.

Comment: @vikingosegundo To be fair, it's obvious *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: @trojanfoe: we don't know if he did omit some code.

Comment: It this the same problem as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165777/objective-c-read-properties-from-another-class ?

Comment: @MartinR it's not the same problem, I can pass those BOOLs without problems. "Doesn't work" means that obj.tabItem is always 'nil'..

Comment: @DrKey: If you alloc/init a ***new instance*** of ThirdViewController then all its properties are of course nil. That is what trojanfoe meant is his comment, and what Olatiar explained in a comment to your previous question.

Comment: @MartinR ok, I understand, but now I don't know how can I solve the problem. May you help me? I'm at beginning with Obj-C :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the current instance of your UITabBarController and then the UITabBarItem you wish to change the badge on.

```
UITabBarController *tabController = self.tabBarController;
NSArray *tabBarItems = tabController.tabBar.items;
UITabBarItem *itemToChangeBadge = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0];
[itemToChangeBadge setBadgeValue:@"!"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't works in AppDelegate cause self.tabBarController doesn't exists in AppDelegate..

Comment: Assuming the UITabBarController is your rootViewController then just do `UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;`